Unexpected result when converting UNICODE to UTF-8 with ICU
I am trying to convert a Hebrew characters into UTF-8 and store them in a std::string.
I thought I'd give ICU a try.
Here is my minimal example:
#include <string>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
   icu::UnicodeString us = L"עידן";
   std::string s;
   us.toUTF8String(s);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

I would expect s to display the same "characters" as the UnicodeString (although in UTF-8).
However, when looking at s in the debugger, the value of the string is: ×¢×™×“×Ÿ.
I am clearly misunderstanding something about how to properly convert these unicode characters to fit and be understood using char.
What am I doing wrong here?

The debugger doesn't know that you intend s to be interpreted as UTF-8 encoded Unicode. I think you're misunderstanding what character encodings are.

@molbdnilo most likely I am. How would I go about storing the example unicode string inside a std::string (if at all possible)?

The expectations are wrong and the method worked perfectly. UTF8 uses multiple bytes for each character outside the 7-bit ASCII range. std::string isn't used for UTF8, it's used for single-byte encodings. The only reason you see it used for UTF8 is that the C++ committee took ages (almost 20 years) to standardize std::u8string, character types like char16_t and char8_t,  and UTF16 literals (u"עידן"). The L prefix was used for 2-byte wchar string literals. UTF16 can use more than 2 bytes. L and wide strings are used on Windows because Windows is natively Unicode since 1994.

@PanagiotisKanavos So std::string cannot store the hebrew characters from the example? Not in a usable manner in any case?

Check String and Character Literals. This shows the different ways to specify strings by version. The basic_string reference shows the various string types in the STL, like u16string, u8string. And best of all, the answers to Convert between std::u8string and std::string which include UTF-8 "support" in C++20 seems to be a bad joke.

@AndréLehto what OS are you running on? On Windows, use u16string or wstring, never string. All text APIs on Windows are Unicode since 1994, with single-byte versions as a compatibility alternative. On Linux, well, the OS isn't natively Unicode and how strings are interpreted depends on the LC_CTYPE/LC_LANG environment variables, which can be different per terminal. If the env variable specifies utf-8, all functions will treat string as UTF8. On MacOS, the GUI is Unicode but each terminal can have its own encoding, even different from the user's profile

That means you can store UTF8 bytes in a string as long as the entire application treats it as a bunch of bytes. You won't be able to depend on the string's length in that case. You'll need to convert when you talk to anything outside the application, including the console, files, databases or OS APIs.

@PanagiotisKanavos Mainly Windows, but it also has to be compatible on Linux.

On Windows, starting of version 1905 (May 2019), it is possible to use UTF-8 in all Win32 and POSIX-like API. I recommend that method as of today, instead of always converting to UTF-16. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page

@prapin So as Panagiotis suggested, setting the process code-page to UTF-8 would make it possible to store UTF-8 bytes in a std::string? Do I understand that right?

@prapin that's not what this says nor is the recommendation good. That link is only for Windows Apps, ie the new types deployed through the store (among other things). Strings remain UTF16 and the Win32 APIs remain UTF16. You can also specify UTF8 as the encoding used by non-Unicode programs (aka the "system" encoding).

Or use u8string so you don't forget you're actually using UTF8 instead of string. If you want to use the same code in both Windows and Linux, even with u8string and char8_t, you'll have to be careful at the edges. On Linux you'll be at the mercy of the user. Check this answer which got updated for C++23, and Tom Honermann's answers in general.

@PanagiotisKanavos Thank you so much for the explanations and links, it helped a lot!

Also check Using std::format for formatting char8_t, char16_t and char32_t texts in C++ 20 and the answers by both vitaut and Tom Honermann. It seems there are still UTF8 problems even in C++ 23 but the /utf-8 switch in the Visual C++ compiler would treat char as UTF8. I haven't used it but this may have the least headaches for now. Check Build and debug on WSL2

@PanagiotisKanavos The project is still stuck on C++17, so I have to take it easy with the C++20 functionalities, unfortunately.

Nothing prevents you to store UTF-8 inside std::string. I would even say, that we should always store UTF-8 inside std::string... But on Windows, if you need to actually use the content of an UTF-8 string in any OS function, including plain fopen you need to set the active code page using a manifest. Unlike what @PanagiotisKanavos understood, this methods works for any application, including plain old command line tools.

@prapin I don't know, I only used and programmed Windows (in C++ and other later other languages) in an non-English locale for over 30 years without problems, and actually remember the transition to Unicode and the fun while non-Unicode applications got ported to Unicode in the early 2000s. Or went out of business. Lots of accounting and financial software companies couldn't rewrite their char based software to work natively on Windows and customers preferred the functionally equivalent software that didn't require fiddling with codepages

std::string is agnostic (or ignorant) for what encoding the string contains.  The debugger does not know what encoding the string contains.  For Visual Studio (CL.EXE), the /utf-8 compiler option helps, but the std::string itself is still encoding agnostic.  Windows APIs and CRT has been UTF-8 friendly for 5 years now.  But C++ itself still has a lot of room for improvement.  (ICU is very useful, and will be for a long time.)

Some related reading: https://tonsky.me/blog/unicode/
and
https://utf8everywhere.org/

The Unicode string עידן encoded in UTF-8 is bytes D7 A2 D7 99 D7 93 D7 9F.  Those same bytes interpreted in a latin-based encoding, like Windows-1252, are characters ×¢×™×“×Ÿ.
So, the actual bytes stored in the std::string are correct (and you can verify this by simply printing out the numeric values of the individual chars in the string). The debugger simply doesn't know the string is encoded in UTF-8 by default and is displaying the raw data using the wrong encoding.
Depending on which debugger you are using, you might be able to tell it the string data is UTF-8 so it displays correctly.  For example, Visual Studio has Format specifiers for its debugger.  In this case, the s8 and s8b specifiers handle UTF-8 strings.
